# For X ∼ Poisson(λ) how can we calculate the coverage probability, confidence set can be obtd using chi square but not the coverage probability?

Tags: statistical-inference, poisson-distribution

For X ∼ Poisson(λ), show that the coverage probability of the confidence interval [L(X),U(X)] is given by ∞ Pλ(λ ∈ [L(X),U(X)]) = x=0 IL(x),U(x)e−λλx x! and that we can define functions xl(λ)andxu(λ)sothat xu(λ) Pλ(λ ∈ [L(X),U(X)]) = x=xl(λ) e−λλx x! .

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.